# Need to get data with laravel when query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, case-when

**I am trying to filter data using when query in Laravel, where it should filter data using the filter $sortBy or $categoryId. Please note the all 3 fields like $id $sortBy $categoryId are optional and will not be presented in all queries**

```
public function Products(Request $request)
{
    $page     = $request->has('page') ? $request->get('page') : 1;
    $limit    = $request->has('itemsPerPage') ? $request->get('itemsPerPage') : 10;
    $sortBy = (($request->sortBy == "popularity")  ? "viewCount" : "created_at");
    $categoryId=  $request->get('categoryId');

    $sellerId = $request->header('id')?SellersBranding::findOrFail($request->header('id')):"Null";
    
    $productLive = ProductsLive::select('productTitle', 'product_id', 'brand_id', 'category_id')
        ->when($sellerId=="Null", function($query)  use ($page, $limit){
            return $query->where('status', 'active')
            ->limit($limit)->offset(($page - 1) * $limit);
        })
        ->when($sortBy, function ($query) use ($sortBy, $sellerId, $page, $limit){
            return $query->orderBy($sortBy, 'DESC')
                ->where('Sid', $sellerId->id)
                ->where('status','active')
                ->limit($limit)->offset(($page - 1) * $limit);
        })
        ->when($categoryId, function ($query) use ($categoryId, $sellerId, $page, $limit) {
            ->where('Sid', $sellerId->id)
                ->where(['category_id' => $categoryId, 'status' => 'active'])
                ->limit($limit)->offset(($page - 1) * $limit)
                ->inRandomOrder();
        })->get();
}
```

**i am new in php and also in laravel please help how to get filtered data**

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what error your getting here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cleanup your code you can check this

```php
public function Products(Request $request)
{
    $page     = $request->has('page') ? $request->get('page') : 1;
    $limit    = $request->has('itemsPerPage') ? $request->get('itemsPerPage') : 10;
    $sortBy = (($request->sortBy == "popularity")  ? "viewCount" : "created_at");
    $categoryId=  $request->filled('categoryId');

    $seller = $request->header('id') ? SellersBranding::findOrFail($request->header('id')): null;

    $productLive = ProductsLive::select('productTitle', 'product_id', 'brand_id', 'category_id')

        ->when($seller ,function ($query) use ($seller){
            $query->where('Sid', $seller->id);
        })

        ->when($categoryId ,function ($query)){
            $query->where('category_id', request('categoryId'))
            ->inRandomOrder();
        })

        ->where('status','active')
        ->orderBy($sortBy, 'DESC')
        ->limit($limit)->offset(($page - 1) * $limit);

    return $productLive;

}
```

here `when()` something filter is coming we are only applying condition.

Not returning each filter as you did

Comment: thanks for your responce i am sending parameters using query string like `?page=1&itemsPerPage=24`  and `?page=1&itemsPerPage=12&categoryId=9` and `page=1&itemsPerPage=24&sortBy=popularity` and `page=1&itemsPerPage=24&sortBy=discount` in this all seller id is optional

Comment: yes `->when($seller)` will apply when you will pass seller and it present in database

Comment: but when i will send categoryId and seller id then this condation how can i get data using both condation

Comment: then both `when()` will true and apply both

Comment: how can i pass in when condation both parameters??

Comment: @khushabukushwaha you didn't understand the code it is `single` query base upon condition it add mutiple fiilter once

Comment: Sir when i am sending `products?page=1&itemsPerPage=24` but its giving `{}` if i'm sending in headers id also giving and `{}` what i'm missing??

Comment: check what sql query is generated and run that sql to mysql

Comment: i got my mistake i am not use `get()`